# Didn't get Database of all value in php file

Tags: php, android

I am creating one `PHP` file that work for sending push notification on android device using `POST` method. When i insert value on `HTML` page data get on `PHP` page but my array of `PHP` didn't take all row values . How can i solve this?

```
<?php
    require "init.php";
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $path_to_fcm='https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $server_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    $sql = "select fcm_token from fcm_info";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    $key = $row[0]; 
    $headers = array('Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
            'Content_Type:application/json');
    $fields = array('to'=>$key,'notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message));
    $payload = json_encode($fields);
    $curl_session = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_URL,$path_to_fcm);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE,CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_session);
    curl_close($curl_session);
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: where is `while` to retrive all data from  `db`

Comment: am new in php just tell me where use loop

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_row($result)` fetches _one single row_ of the result set, so one single entry. You have to loop and execute that command until you have read all entries.

Answer (score 1):

```
$key_array=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  array_push($key_array,$row['fcm_token']);
}
```

Comment: @Atish try updated code and confirm your record in the table is more than one  or make sure your fcm_token are in right format like length wise